# pgfplots: How to align dateplot with two x axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, axis, dateplot

Assumed we have this Minimum Working Example (MWE) to display a `dateplot` with two completely identical `x axis`, but with different `xtick` positions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis x line*        = top,
            axis y line*        = left,
            date coordinates in = x,
            xtick               = {2018-11-15,2018-12-15,2019-01-15,2019-02-15,2019-03-15,2019-04-15,2019-05-15},
            xticklabels         = {Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,March,Apr,May},
            date ZERO           = 2018-11-01;
            xmin                = 2018-11-01;
            xmax                = 2019-05-01;
            ]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
            axis x line*        = bottom,
            axis y line*        = right,
            date coordinates in = x,
            xtick               = {2018-11-01,2018-12-01,2019-01-01,2019-02-01,2019-03-01,2019-04-01,2019-05-01},
            xticklabels         = {Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,March,Apr,May},
            date ZERO           = 2018-11-01;
            xmin                = 2018-11-01;
            xmax                = 2019-05-01;
            ]
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

- Despite of setting all `xticks` manually with `xtick = {2019-01-15,...}`, they falsely appear on the completely same position like `xticks` at very different dates of the second `x axis`, e.g. `xtick = {2019-01-01,...}`.
- Furthermore, the month `Nov` is completely missing (thanks marmot!)

**Question:**

How can I align the `xticks` precisely without failure shifts in `x` direction? While the upper `x axis` should display the mean days of the month (e.g. `2019-01-15`), the lower `x axis` should display the start dates of the month (e.g. `2019-01-01`).

Comment: @marmot: The very first time that even you don't understand confusing LaTeX-behavior? :-)

Comment: I guess the issue is simply that you use semicolons instead of commas in `date ZERO           = 2018-11-01 00:00:00;` (should be `date ZERO           = 2018-11-01 00:00:00,`), `xmin` and `xmax`.

Comment: @marmot: Great idea! Unfortunately the values of both axis move simultaneously when replacing the semicolons with commas.

Comment: Furthermore, the november is still missing. :-)

Comment: I agree. So I think there should be no semicolons but the issue you describe is then still there. (will decouple now...)

Comment: If you plot something, such as `\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(2019-1-1,0)};`, the `xmin` and `xmax` settings work properly, and november shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug, but as mentioned in a comment if you plot something the axis limits work as expected. So if you, in addition to fixing the semicolon-issue mentioned by marmot, add `\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(2019-1-1,0)};` in each axis, the output is this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis x line*        = top,
            axis y line*        = left,
            date coordinates in = x,
            xtick               = {2018-11-15,2018-12-15,2019-01-15,2019-02-15,2019-03-15,2019-04-15,2019-05-15},
            xticklabels         = {Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,March,Apr,May},
            date ZERO           = 2018-11-01,
            xmin                = 2018-11-01,
            xmax                = 2019-05-01
            ]
\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(2019-1-1,0)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
            axis x line*        = bottom,
            axis y line*        = right,
            date coordinates in = x,
            xtick               = {2018-11-01,2018-12-01,2019-01-01,2019-02-01,2019-03-01,2019-04-01,2019-05-01},
            xticklabels         = {Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,March,Apr,May},
            date ZERO           = 2018-11-01,
            xmin                = 2018-11-01,
            xmax                = 2019-05-01
            ]
\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(2019-1-1,0)};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```